# Divergence of $\frac{1}{ r^2}\hat{{\bf r}}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the vector $\mathbf{\vec{v}}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$

For the divergence of $\mathbf{\vec{v}}$ in Spherical coordinates:

$\bigtriangledown \cdot \mathbf{\vec{v}}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left ( r^{2}v_{r} \right )$
where 
$v_{r}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}$

I have a problem with with $v_{r}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ as my work gives $
\frac{-2}{r^{3}}$

Am I misinterpreting anything?

Answer (score 2):

Check this in Cartesian coordinates:
\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} &=
  \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{x}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}},
                      \frac{y}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}},
                      \frac{z}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \right) \\
  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
     \left[ \frac{x}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \right]+
     \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
     \left[ \frac{y}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \right]+
     \frac{\partial}{\partial z}
     \left[ \frac{z}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}}-
     \frac{3x^{2}}{2(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{5/2}}+
     \frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}} \\
  &\quad -
     \frac{3y^{2}}{2(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{5/2}}+
     \frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}}-
     \frac{3z^{2}}{2(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{5/2}} \\
  &= \frac{3(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})-3(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})}
     {2(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{5/2}} \\
  &=0
\end{align*}

In spherical coordinates:
\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}
  &= \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}
     \left( r^{2} v_{r} \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}
     \left( r^{2} \times \frac{1}{r^{2}} \right) \\
  &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't get how one arrives at $1/r^{2}$
What is this v? Surely, this isn't the vector $\vec{v}$

Comment: $\mathbf{v}$ is printing style while $\vec{v}$ is handwriting style.  We denote $v_{r}$ as the component of $\mathbf{v}$ along the radial direction. Now $\mathbf{v}=\frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^{2}}=v_{r} \hat{\mathbf{r}}$, i.e. $v_{r}=\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ in this case.

Comment: Sometimes we denote $\mathbf{e}_{r}$ as the unit vector along radial direction.

Comment: @NgChungTak But $$\nabla \cdot \hat {r\over r^2} = 4\pi \delta^3 (\vec r)$$ no ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is a slight misinterpretation of the notation "$\square_r$". In many cases, it indicates a partial or ordniary derivative which is your interpretation (and completely understandable). In cases with vectors, and divergences, it can either mean that, or the "$r$" component of the vector Which would be $\frac{1}{r^2}$, not its derivative. If you need to remember it next time, remember that divergences should only go up to first order derivatives of the vector, not second derivatives. Laplacians are completely different scenario.